# LTspice .raw file not showing

Tags: python

[.asc showing instead of black screen .raw file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXUhi.png)

Using LTspice for a uni module and followed instructions on how to download and use it.
However, I cannot get it to show me the .raw file that displays the waveform. All I get are numbers (as seen in the image). I have not touched anything in LTspice so someone please help me because this is driving nutz.

I googled to find a solution but nothing popped up.